# run PHP code inside HTML without using xampp and apache?

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

i know there are many similar questions but tbh none of them really fit.

I have no problems running the php part of my Webpage and everything works fine. Now im asking if there is a way to run my webpage including the php part without using having to start apache and typing in localhost.

I just wanna open up my html document with a browser and display it, nothing else. However then, the php code isnt really executed but its necessary for me as it displays an essential table with data. And no I cant use javascript for a very specific reason. I have to use php for my project but its a bit inconvenient having to start apache everytime and i just want to open up the document with firefox for example.

Comment: No, PHP is a server-side language, it doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: I can see that you don't like how servers work and you really don't like people telling you how they work. So here's the deal. IF YOU have such a problem with running PHP then have it run automatically on your system startup. ``` PHP -S localhost:8000```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this will not be possible as PHP is a server side language. As such, you will have to have an application to serve the content. With HTML, you are able to open it directly and display as the client (Browser) is able to read it directly. Browsers do not read PHP - when the server compiles the PHP, it is only sending the DOM (HTML, etc.) to the browser.

Comment: ok now I get it, makes perfect sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like other people said, PHP is a server side language so you need to run a server on your machine.
But maybe you could try using small local server like the [Symfony Local Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html)

It should be faster to start than apache.